# array_walk_recursive, function using variable outside in PHP

Tags: php

```
   $total_materials_cost = 0;
   array_walk_recursive($materials, function($item, $key) {
        if (in_array($key, array('id'))) {

                    (....)

                    $total = $material_price * $material['amount'];

                    $total_materials_cost += $total;
                }
            }
        }
    });
echo $total_materials_cost;
```

For the above code I get error at line `$total_materials_cost += $total;` , says the variable is undefined - I believe this is because that I am inside a function? But how can I in any way bypass/ make a workaround for this, so it does add to the variable?

Comment: I find it VERY unlikely that you need a recursive approach.  It is more likely, if needing any special iterating at all, that you just need nested loops.  If the subarrays have consistent depth, using recursion is needless overhead and `array_walk_recursive()` will unnecessarily visiting every leafnode.  This old question really would have benefited from sample input.  Also, `in_array()` is another needless overhead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `use` keyword:

```
$total_materials_cost = 0;
array_walk_recursive($materials, function($item, $key) use(&$total_materials_cost) {
  if (in_array($key, array('id'))) {
    // (....)
    $total = $material_price * $material['amount'];
    $total_materials_cost += $total;
  }
});
echo $total_materials_cost;
```

Pass a reference (`&`) to change a variable outside the closure.

Comment: error gone but $total_materials_cost is 0 and does not add

Comment: @Karem: Sorry, missed that. Please see my updated answer.